# How to write the repsonse, of GET method to a ServiceNow API, to a output file and download it to my local machine in the script?

Tags: scripting, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

how do i write the result variable to an output file and download that to my local machine in this script.

something like gs.writeFile("path_to_localFile.filetype", result) so that it will get downloaded in my local machine.

```
var httpclient = Packages.org.apache.commons.httpclient;
var HttpClient = httpclient.HttpClient;
var UsernamePasswordCredentials = httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
var AuthScope = httpclient.auth.AuthScope;
var GetMethod = httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

var client = new HttpClient();
var authScope = new AuthScope("myInstance.service-now.com", 443, null);
var credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myUsername", "myPassword");
client.getState().setCredentials( authScope, credentials);

var get = new GetMethod( "https://myInstance.service-now.com/sys_soap_message.do?XML&sysparm_query=active=true");

get.setDoAuthentication( true );

var status = client.executeMethod( get );

var headers = get.getResponseHeaders();

for (var i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
  gs.print(headers[i].getName() + ":"+headers[i].getValue());
}

var result = (status + "\n" + get.getResponseBodyAsString()).replace(/</g, "&"+"lt;");
gs.print(result);


get.releaseConnection();
```

Comment: does it have to be done in `servicenow`, or can you use another language such as Python, JavaScript?

Comment: I want it to be inside servicenow Fix Scripts